# why does not submit button work correctly in yii2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, submit-button

I am using Kartik tabs to organise my form into multiple forms. For that I divided my form into 3 views where each view represent a tab and contains a part of my form. My problem is that the submitbutton can get the data only from one form and not from all the forms. 
Can any one give me a simple exemple to help me?

Here I post the kartik tabs link where I have installed it: http://demos.krajee.com/tabs-x
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For submitting two or more forms with one button you will have to use JavaScript.

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit()" />
```

Notice that I'm using `type="button"` which is different from `type="submit"`. Button is just a button you can add functionality on it using JavaScript, it won't submit form on its own.

And `onclick="submit()"` event handler captures a click event from
the users’ mouse button on the element to which the
onclick attribute is applied. This action usually
results in a call to a script method such as a JavaScript function, like `submit()`

Your forms must have IDs.

And here's JavaScript code for submitting two forms with one button using their IDs:

```
submit = function(){
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
    document.getElementById("form2").submit();
}
```

If you decide to use a regular submit button, you could add an onclick event to it that does the follow:

```
document.getElementById('otherForm').submit();
```

Comment: It is not working for me. plz can you give me a basic example using yii2. I need an example on the view and the controller's action.